# Spark: Export graph data to anything (Hive, text, etc)

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-spark, rdd

I have a Spark Graph that I created this way

```
val graph = Graph(vertices, edges, defaultArticle).cache
```

My vertices is an `RDD[(Long, (String, Option[String], List[String], Option[String])]` and my edges is an `RDD[Edge[Long]]`

How do I save this graph/Edges/Vertices to Hive/Text File/Anything else, and how would I read it back? I looked into Spark SQL doc and Spark core doc but I still don't succeed. If I do `saveAsTextFile()` then when I read it back it's an `RDD[String]`, which is not what I need....

**EDIT:** Daniel has provided an answer to save as an object file... I'm still interested in understanding how to save and read the object above as a Hive table. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `rdd.saveAsTextFile()`/`sc.textFile()` use `rdd.saveAsObjectFile()`/`sc.objectFile()`. This will use normal Java serialization for each line, stored as a Hadoop SequenceFile.

Comment: You would have to use a `case class` for your lines, and then use SparkSQL. I haven't tried writing to Hive this way myself, so I cannot offer a code example. Perhaps someone can chime in.